# Dynamic remarketing tag for home and searchresults pages

Tags: google-ads-api

i have to implement the dynamic remarketing tag to my site.
(using custom tags as the marketing company i use suggest me)

I have implement the product page easily

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var google_tag_params = {
        dynx_itemid: '<?=$product_id?>',
        dynx_itemid2: '',
        dynx_pagetype: 'offerdetail',
        dynx_totalvalue: <?=$price?>,
    };
</script>
```

What its not clear for me is what to do on home and category pages.

I am searching google to find an example that will clear things but no luck.

So my real question is "do i set the dynx_itemid on home and category pages indicating the products the user is listing  or i simply set dynx_pagetype to indicate that this is a remarketing user"

For setting the dynx_itemid on home and category pages the code will be something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var google_tag_params = {
            dynx_itemid: [1,2,3,], // the products ids of the listing
            dynx_itemid2: '',
            dynx_pagetype: 'searchresults' //or home

        };
</script>
```

For setting only the dynx_pagetype on home and category pages the code will be something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var google_tag_params = {
            dynx_itemid: ''
            dynx_itemid2: '',
            dynx_pagetype: 'searchresults' //or home

        };
</script>
```

Which approach is the correct one?

Answer (score -1):

On a page of type `searchresults`, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/parameters#other-sites) states that you should include all product IDs that are shown.

Not so on the the `home` page. As for `category`, it doesn't exist as value for the `dynx_pagetype` parameter.

Maybe the [retail sites parameters](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/parameters#retail-sites) would be more appropriate for your use case if you have category pages?